# Do not Transfer File when Data Extension is empty!

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I think the title says it all. Is it possible in *Automation Studio* to prevent a *File Transfer Activity* from the file to FTP if the designated Data Extension contains no rows?

**UPDATE:**

Screenshot of the *Verification Activity* suggested in the comments.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you need to add a Verification activity before the File Transfer activity.

> Avoid unintended outcomes by verifying the data used in an Automation
>   Studio automation.
>
> Use the Verification activity to avoid unintended automation outcomes.
>   The activity lets you select a target data extension in your
>   automation and evaluate the target data extension for conditions you
>   set.

So basically you check if there are any records in your DE, and if there aren't any, you stop the automation from running further steps:

[image]

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_verification_activity.htm&type=5

Comment: Thank you! This could be the solution. But I have a bit of difficulty with this. My file is being exported regardless. There is one header row and no records in it. I have tried with two conditions "Count greater than 0" and "Count greater than 1". Any clues?

Comment: This is confusing because I am still getting the file in the Export folder of FTP.

Comment: @Disasterkid is it possible that it's the old file which was exported earlier today?

Comment: I empty the FTP directory and notice a new file showing up. It also has the hour and minute timestamp on its name.

Comment: @Disasterkid so the automation doesn't stop, like in the screenshot I just added to my answer?

Comment: Now I know what I did wrong. The condition should be "Count equal to 0" because that is when I wanted to stop the automation. Your answer is right. Thanks!

Comment: @Disasterkid glad it worked :-)